# Getting hash from module in to the main Perl code

Tags: perl, hash, module

This is the first time, I am working with module. I am trying to retrieve the content of a hash present in the module into main perl code.

Below is the module DRUG.pm

```
package DRUG;
require Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(%DRUG);

%DRUG = (
    'warfarin ' => 1,
    'midazolam ' => 1,
    'acebutolol ' => 1,
);
```

Here is the main program, trying to access hash present in the module

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use DRUG;

foreach my $nme (keys %DRUG){
print "$nme\n";
}
```

I am unable to get hash information from module and could not print that hash in the main perl code.

Can some one help me in this?

THanks

Comment: I declared use drugnames instead of use DRUG; in the main program. Just edited.

Comment: You shouldn't fix the problem in your question. It makes the answer read rather oddly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
use DrugNames;
```

be

```
use DRUG;
```

And you need a `1;` at the end of the DRUGS.pm

Comment: I have made corrections what you suggested. I still get this error: Global symbol "%DRUG1" requires explicit package name at invitro.pl line 11.
Execution of invitro.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

While it is simple to use the Exporter to make the contents of DRUG available,
using an "accessor" method is often preferred.

This has the advantage that your current name space is not "polluted" with variables from the package.

Also if your don't wish to have the contents changed consider making the variable Readonly.

## file main.pl

`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use DRUG;

my $drug = DRUG->get_drug();
foreach my $nme (keys %$drug){
    print "$nme\n";
}
```

`

## file DRUG.pm

`

```
package DRUG;
use strict;
use Readonly;

Readonly my $DRUG => {
    'warfarin ' => 1,
    'midazolam ' => 1,
    'acebutolol ' => 1,
};

sub get_drug{
    return $DRUG;
}

1;
```

`